# Get WORKSPACE root in Bazel BUILD

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm using [rules_protobuf](https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf) to build Python language bindings for my `helloworld.proto` file.  My `helloworld.proto` imports [wrappers.proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto).

```
syntax = "proto3";

package main;

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
```

My BUILD file

```
load("@org_pubref_rules_protobuf//python:rules.bzl", "py_proto_compile")

# Wrapper around proto_compile.
# https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf/blob/master/protobuf/internal/proto_compile.bzl

py_proto_compile(
    name = "py",
    with_grpc = True,
    protos = ["helloworld.proto"],
    imports = ["/usr/local/home/username/myproject/include"]
)
```

The `wrappers.proto` file is located in the directory

```
/usr/local/home/username/myproject/include
```

The Bazel rule `py_proto_compile` is defined by [rules_protobuf](https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf) and [documented in the README.md](https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf/tree/master/protobuf#proto_compile). `imports` is defined as:

- **Name:** `imports`
- **Type:** string_list`
- **Description:** Optional paths to be passed as -I arguments to the protoc tool.
- **Default:** `[]`

My BUILD rules works, however I've hard-coded the location of of `wrappers.proto` with:

`imports = ["/usr/local/home/username/myproject/include"]`

Bazel doesn't appear to have any [predefined Make variables](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html#predefined_variables) that reference my WORKSPACE root. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

`imports = ["$WORKSPACE_ROOT"/include"]`

Answer (score 6):

**NEW UPDATE:**

There is also a more elaborate way of doing it. Check [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3114) out. Have a look at the lines where it says:

`# Grab a reference to the root of the users project
project_dir = ctx.path(ctx.attr.file_in_project).dirname`

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can use `__workspace_dir__` to get the path to the current working directory (*i.e.* the directory containing the `WORKSPACE` file).

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/4d0a571ff9c15b937f58d3d5e97a5310b5decf2b/tensorflow_serving/workspace.bzl

Comment: I find the old answer better as it does not require the custom rule to contain at least one attribute pointing to a file in the calling workspace.